# Javascript "if" statement within alert

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm wondering how to embed "if" statements within alerts.  Specifically, I'm working on a form, and I want the alert that appears after the user clicks "Submit" to display different messages depending on which elements of the user's input are problematic (if any).  I know that I could do it the other way around (i.e., use a series of if statements to determine which alert to show), but I was hoping to be able to use "if/else" within the alert code itself.  Thanks!

Comment: No, and besides why would you want to? It's much more readable and logical to write "if this alert that, else if this alert that..."

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, not necessarily. It would make sense to see something like `alert(getMessage())`, where `getMessage` contains the necessary `if` statements.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it didn't seem to work (I'm not terribly familiar with JavaScript syntax).  And I wanted to use the if statement because the script should display one message all the time and then add optional values...I know it could be done otherwise, but I just want to know if it's possible to put the if statement in the alert...

Comment: Please show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably as a reduced test case in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use an alert. It's used exclusively to inform the user that something has occurred, and you can't exactly get feedback from it. What you should use instead is a prompt or a confirm. Using the confirm code will allow you to determine whether the user hit OK or Cancel. While this is very limited, it still functions in a manner similar to what you're looking for. For example

```
var r=confirm("Press a button");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
```

Using the prompt code will allow the user to input a value, which you can then append to a variable and use logic from there, such as

```
var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (person!=null)
  {
  x="Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
```

The standard syntax for the prompt function is

```
prompt("This text will appear in the alert box","This is the default value");
```

My source, as well as additional information, is available at [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Edit - I forgot to mention that, if they're using a form you've made in javascript, it could be easier just to run a simple if/else statement that checks if all of the values they've input are not null and have the right datatype before allowing them to continue. Have the else be the alert, I suppose, if you're using the if to confirm validity, as opposed to a lack thereof.

Comment: What's wrong with W3schools? He said he doesn't understand much syntax, and that's a great place to get started. I mean, really, correct me if I'm wrong. That's what I was taught to use as a reference when I first started out, and it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like

```
alert(condition ? "Text if true": "text if false");
```

But it wouldn't be the most readable code. The commented options of

```
alert(getAlertMessage(anyNeededValue));
```

or

```
if (cond) {
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

sound better. But if you really keen on that "if in the alert", here you have an inline function:

```
alert((function(){ 
    if (cond) { return "Text when true";}
    else {return "Text when false");})());
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert` takes a string as an input. Which can come from a variable.

```
var message;

if ("condition1") {
  message = "message1";
} else if ("condition2") {
  message = "message2";
} else if ("condition3") {
  message = "message3";
}

alert(message);
```

Unfortunately `if` is a statement, and can't be directly used as an argument. But you can use the ternary operator instead, which is an expression.

```
alert(if ("this") { "won't" } else { "work"} );
alert('but' ? 'this' : 'will');
```

This is also possible, altough I've never seen it used:

```
alert(
  ('condition1') ? 
   'result1' : 
  ('condition2') ? 
   'result2' : 
   'result3'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable:

```
msg = "";
if (…)
    msg = "error 1";
else if (…)
    msg = "error 2";
[…]

if (msg.length)
    alert(msg);
```

> I was hoping to be able to use "if/else" within the alert <s>code</s> call

You could use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is basically an else-if inside an expression - which means that the expression as a whole can be passed as an argument:

```
 alert( /* condition */ ? "error 1" : "everything is fine" );
```